# Javascript animation infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple animation in javascript (I can't use css) and I don't seem to make it infinite. this is what I have so far:

```
  myMove(ball , i, size) {
          var id = setInterval(frame, 3* i);
    function frame() {
      if (size == 100) {
        size = 0;
      } else {
        size++; 
        ball.style.width = size/10 + 'px'; 
        ball.style.height = size/10 + 'px';
      }
    } 
}
```

the ball would be the element, the i is the iterated element in a for loop in which the function is called for each element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfBalls; i++{
   myMove(document.getElementByClassName[i]('ball'), i, 10)
}
```

and size is the max size I wish my element expands to. 
I wish to have a smooth transition, where the 5 balls will expand in succession (so first ball after 300ms, the second, after 300ms the third and so on) and when the last ball has expanded, repeat the process. I'm really struggling to get a decent result. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName[i]('ball')` I'm pretty sure the array index should go *after* the parentheses

Comment: Problem with my approach is that the animations are really really fast and messy